# Database design restaurant menu

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I am struggling with the design of entities for a relational database. I am setting up an online restaurant menu, for dynamically loading in an application. I have come up with the following entities based on my understanding of the menu.

- There are Menu Categories (e.g. Mains, Sides, Drinks, Desserts)
- There are Menu Items in each Category (Burger, Chips, Salad, etc.)
- This is simple, but the problem I am facing is with a category of menu items   which has a second type of MenuItems which are a combination of other Menu Items. Take for
  example, a meal deals category in Mcdonald's menu which include a burger +
  fries + drink. In this case it is a combination of three different
  categories (burger, sides, and drink) and the user can choose from
  multiple options in that category. And there are many such combinations present in the meal deals category.

How should I design the db in such a way that is useful in creating combinations of other simple MenuItems from different categories. Ideally, I should be able to create new more than one categories which have such special combination menu items, but at the moment I am trying with just one category dedicated for such items.

So far, I have tried, to create a separate entity of comboMenuItems which has all the attributes of a MenuItem (name, description, price, etc.) except that their category is fixed to be (MealDeals category coming from the Category table).

To make the situation more complex, sometimes a meal deal has a quantity associated with it, which means a client can select more than one item from a category. An example for this may be a family deal which includes 2 burgers, 2 sides, and a drink. I am not sure how to design the db to cater this business rule.

There are some other details of the MenuItems (like variations, options, etc) but I am omitting them from this question just to make it easy to understand.

I am looking for the entities and relationships that can handle this situation.

The goal is to be able to create new combination deals in the db, and present them in a dynamic menu page, with the ultimate goal of creating a cart that deals with ordering from that menu.

Comment: Please give some specific complete designs that actually represent the available choices, without worrying about how "good" they are, how concise they are, or how tedious that is. You could begin by thinking of all the possible ways one can complete the sentence "i would like to order...".

Answer (score 0):

You could have a seperate table for meal deals, where each meal deal has a unique ID to identify that meal deal, a price, and a list of the items which can go into that meal deal, you could even seperate them by their type of course - mains, sides, drinks etc. and store them in a comma ',' or pipe '|' separated list. then you have a clever little lookup query to identify whether the selected items are part of a meal deal.

For example,
ID:1,Price:3.50,MainIDs:1|7|14|15|16|19,SideIDs:4|5|7|11,DrinkIDs:5|6|7

then, say for example, a customer adds main 1, side 4 and drink 5 to their basket, your query does a lookup to return all the meal deal IDs (and prices) which contain that combination of items.

Hopefully I've understood your question properly, and I hope this helps.

Comment: is it a relational design or a work around? I can see there will be issues of enforcing constraints because there is no enforced relationship between menuItem and mealDeals.

Comment: @Novice Any database design, of whatever paradigm, no matter how perverse, can be described relationally, usually at least as concisely. Here we have a table holding rows where "deal ID has price PRICE and allows main in MAINIDS and side in SIDEIDS and drink in DRINKIDS". We can get rid of the multivalued attributes, so that we can query about their parts, via multiple tables: "deal ID has price PRICE", "deal ID allows main MAINID", "deal ID allows side SIDEID" & "deal ID allows drink DRINKID". First find tables to describe all possible application situations. Worry about constraints later.

Comment: It is worth noting that if you put extra work into it, you could take the example given, and put a new row (a new meal deal) for each main, side and drink combination possible within the list for that deal.